# when run the document.ready() event ,some times ajax request not working properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

```
var casualDays;
var days;

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $(function(){
        $('select, input').styledSelect();
    });

    $(function (){
    var usernameSelected = $("input#Employee_UserName" ).val().toString();
    var username;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetLeaveConsumedDays", "ApplyLeave")',
        type: 'POST',

        data: { username: usernameSelected },

        success: function (results) {
           days=results;
        }, 
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
    });
    $(function (){
    var usernameSelected = $("input#Employee_UserName" ).val().toString();
    var username;
    $.ajax({
        url:'@Url.Action("GetLeaveConsumedDaysCasual", "ApplyLeave")',
        type: 'POST',

        data: { username: usernameSelected },

        success: function (results) {
           casualDays=results;
        }, 
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
    });
```

K

this is my document.ready event, After run the page its work two or three time correctly.but after several times its not working properly.its not giving value for 'days' and 'casualdays' there value are get some error.After refreshing two or three time again its work.I cant think what is the reason for that.please any one can help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax is Asynchronous, you have to wait until the requests are complete before you can access `days` and `casualdays`.

```
var foo; 
alert(foo); // undefined 1

$.ajax({ 
    url: "foo.php", 
    success: function(data){
        foo = data // foo now equals data
        alert(foo); // NOT undefined! 3
    }
});

alert(foo); // still undefined 2
```

Comment: inside of ajax foo is defined

Comment: @iJD "is defined" === "NOT undefined" double negative

Comment: No Its not a problem about varible define or undefine,

Comment: Its not a problem about the variable define or undefined. after run the document.ready function when use those varible first two or three time its work after that their value assign to html error.

Comment: That's just it. sometimes it will work others it won't. What's happening is sometimes the request happens fast enough, other times it doesn't. That's a race condition. Only use the data from the ajax request inside the success callback or inside a done callback. Storing that data in a global variable is rarely a good idea.